# more trouble with the R `{}` wrapper and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

An earlier question I had (with answer) illustrates how the `{}` wrapper prevents piping to the first possible argument. Now I'm playing with this idea in the following manner.

```
# this all works
library(tidyverse)
mt <- mtcars %>% count(cyl)
seq_along(mt$cyl)
```

That code chunk aboves works. Neither of the two below work. I get an error, *"Error in function_list[k] : object 'cyl' not found".* What did I do wrong this time?

```
# does not work
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  {seq_along(cyl)}

#does not work
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  seq_along(cyl)
```

If none of my stuff makes sense **all I really need** is the simplest example of how the `{}` wrapper works with dplyr. Thank you.

Comment: With the curly braces you refer to the dataset piped in with `.`.  Like `mtcars %>% count(cyl) %>% {seq_along(.$cyl)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  {seq_along(.$cyl)}
```

The object is still passed as `.` with the braces, but it's not automatically inserted in to the first parameter.

In your first case

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  {seq_along(cyl)}
```

is the same as these two separate commands

```
count(mtcars, cyl)
seq_along(cyl)
```

because you never actually use anything from the chain. And your second case

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  seq_along(cyl)
```

is the same as

```
seq_along(count(mtcase, cyl), cyl)
```

which doesn't work because `seq_along` isn't a tidy-friendly function in that it doesn't accept a data source as the first parameter.